# When loading & resizing external images, does the browser loads external images with their full width and then re-sizes them?

Tags: html, browser

If I load external images of 320x240 px and re-size them using CSS, the browser loads the full images first and then re-sizes them?

So by resizing I am just adding more load to the server?

Should I display them without resizing?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser downloads the original file, no extra processing is done on the server.  The resizing is done by the browser.

Comment: And the resizing can make my website slower? I dont know which is faster, displaying them as 320x240 or resizing

Comment: I believe it's fairly negligible. Ideally you would have the images at the correct size on the server, but sometimes that's not possible.

Comment: I mean its not a problem for me to display them full width, so if this helps I'll stop resizing them.

Answer (score 0):

As said, yes, the browser downloads the original and then resizes it. Be warned that some browsers are not very good at resizing images, especially if the original is much larger than the actual output. Some browsers (Firefox comes to mind) create rather blocky versions if they shrink pictures.